# drawer menu fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

Hi i i was using the default android "navigation drawer menu" in android studio , i got my fragments going greatly , but i have 1 problem.

[image]

I need to be able to change the "User" and email from there , not using xml , but get it from firebase.

i was able to get the reference and everything and put it into a toast , but when ever i try and change the text from the nav_header_menu.xml using my Main.java the application crashe's.

i wanted to state that its the same problem here. i want to be able to programatically be able to change the menu that shows here:

[image]

My main question is that how can i be able to change these programmatically using java fragments? as that would actually help me alot, pointing me in the right direction is also greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change like this.
Get Username from Firebase or anything and change it like this.

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
TextView navUsername = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.navUsername);
navUsername.setText("Your Text Here");
```

Comment: thanks for the help , sorry for the late rep , was super busy with work the other day sadly T_T , this really helped me a lot!